# Join two collections in mongodb using laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

My existing setup

- Laravel 5.2
- Mongo 3.0.12
- Jenssegers\Mongodb -> MongoDB based Eloquent model

Now
Student.php

```
<?php
class Student extends Moloquent {

protected $fillable = [
    'college_id','status',"firstname"
];

protected $collection = 'student';

public function colleges()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("College", 'college_id');
}
```

Sample data in student collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd1"),
    "firstname" : "S1",
    "college_id" : "68ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd1",
    "status" : 1,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd2"),
    "firstname" : "S2",
    "college_id" : "68ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd1",
    "status" : 1,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd3"),
    "firstname" : "S3",
    "college_id" : "68ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd1",
    "status" : 1,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd4"),
    "firstname" : "S4",
    "college_id" : "68ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd2",
    "status" : 1,
}
```

College.php

```
<?php
class College extends Moloquent {

protected $fillable = [
    'name','dep_ids'
];

protected $collection = 'college';
```

Sample data in College collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("68ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd1"),
    "name" : "C1",
    "dep_ids" : ['IT','EC','AERO','ME']
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("68ff4ad56c452c1ad37bddd2"),
    "name" : "C2",
    "dep_ids" : ['IT','EC']
}
```

Now I want all students data on following condition

1. Student status must be 1
2. College must have more than 3 departments(dep_ids)

And one more thing **data must fetch in pagination wise** (Like in mysql query we can use LIMIT 0,10 or LIMIT 10,10)

Any help please ?

Note:
I know about $lookup (aggregation) but I can't use it as my mongo db version is 3.0.12 which is not support this aggregation. And I can't upgrade it (please don't ask why as it is long story)
I found that map reduce can help but I don't know how to use it